# Insert a calculated value into database PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, sql-insert

I have three table

```
LineItem       Orders        Product

order_id       order_id      product_id
product_id     order_date    product_name
quantity       customer_id   list_price
price          employee_id
               total
```

I want to insert new value to line item with price is calculated as price = quantity * product.list_price
How can I use INSERT INTO to do that?

Comment: Aside from the answers to your direct problem, I'd question your inclusion of 'total' in the ORDERS table.  Total of what?  I'd assume the total value of the order - as in sum of LINE_ITEM.PRICE for that ORDER_ID.  If so, I guarantee you will end up with a disconnect.  One of the fundamental rules of data normalization is to never store that which can be calculated, and this appears to be a prime example. Rather than storing the sum of PRICE, and trying to keep it accurate, just calculate it when you need it.

Comment: The total is total number of lineItem for given order_id.

Comment: Whaterver, same thing applies.  Don't store that which can be calculated at run time.  You can easily SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LINE_ITEM WHERE LINE_ITEM.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID;  If you try to store that in ORDERS, it is only a matter of time before something unexpected happens and ORDERS does not get updaated properly, and so will have an incorrect value.  This is Relational Database Design 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `insert ... select` syntax. Assuming that you want to insert `order_id` `1`, `product_id` 2 and `quantity` `3`:

```
insert into line_item(order_id, product_id, quantity, price)
select 
    1,
    product_id,
    3,
    3 * list_price
from product
where product_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

GMB's solution is perfect. You can also use update on top of this if you want to update the price of all existing rows in the table.

```
UPDATE l
SET l.price = p.list_price * l.quantity
FROM LineItem l
JOIN Product p ON p.product_id = l.product_id
```